# Toxiproxy in Spring Boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to experiment Toxiproxy in a SpringBoot test (for a poc) to inject a latency and have this simple test class but the latency toxic I'm setting does not seem to have any effect at all and I'm not sure if I'm missing something?

I'm basically trying to ping google.com and expecting a latency to delay the response (display of the line:

```
System.out.println(reachable);
```

but it is immediately logging it.

Any hints would be appreciated.

```
@Testcontainers
public class ToxiproxyTest {

  @LocalServerPort
  private int port;

  // Toxiproxy container, which will be used as a TCP proxy
  @Container
  public static ToxiproxyContainer toxiproxy = new ToxiproxyContainer("ghcr.io/shopify/toxiproxy:2.5.0")
      .withNetwork(Network.newNetwork());

  private Proxy proxy;


  @SneakyThrows
  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    ToxiproxyClient toxiproxyClient = new ToxiproxyClient(toxiproxy.getHost(), toxiproxy.getControlPort());
    proxy = toxiproxyClient.createProxy("proxy", toxiproxy.getHost() + ":" + port, "www.google.com:80");
  }

  @SneakyThrows
  @Test
  public void testLatency() {
    proxy.toxics().latency("latency", ToxicDirection.DOWNSTREAM, 200000L);

    Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
    int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
    boolean reachable = (returnVal==0);
    System.out.println(reachable);
  }
```